# In WPF if we create multiple rectangles using item-container , then rectangles are getting overlapped on each other

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters, rectangles

[image]

In WPF if we create multiple rectangles using item-container , then rectangles are getting overlapped on each other with inconsistent gaps?

Here you can see from 0-100 rectangle should be separated consistently but that didn't happened and then from 120-200 you can observe overlapping and shades.

**Note: All the values coming from converters are perfectly fine. So converters are not the issue.

I tried different ways like using SnapDeviceToPixels and RenderTransform too but it didn't worked

`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HighLightRegions}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=myRectangle}"
                                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myRectangle}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.Style>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle >
                        <Style>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="plotLineViewModel:HighLightRectType">
                            <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=PlotArea}">                              
                                <Rectangle Fill= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.FrameOverlayColor}" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           Opacity=".6" Stroke="{StaticResource MyChartPlotBackgroundBrush}"
                                           Height ="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=myRectangle}">
                                    <Canvas.Left>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource  ChartViewXCordinateConverter}" >
                                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="myRectangle" />
                                            <Binding Path="Location.X" />
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.XAxisMax" ElementName="XPosition"/>
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.XAxisMin" ElementName="XPosition"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Canvas.Left>
                                    <Rectangle.Width>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource  ChartViewXCordinateConverter}" >
                                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="myRectangle" />
                                            <Binding Path="Width" />
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.XAxisMax" ElementName="XPosition" />
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.XAxisMin"  ElementName="XPosition"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Rectangle.Width>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Canvas>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

`

Comment: consider using a uniformgrid with only one row instead of the canvas. Now you dont need to care around the x axis anymore as they will just be evenly spaced one after another and resize accordingly. If this is not what you are after i am sure you calculation for Location.X is wrong

Comment: I tried Grid too but same issue. Also about Location.X values are coming perfectly fine